# Why does docker-compose create the source directory in one syntax but not the other?

Tags: windows, docker, docker-compose

Consider the following YAML code in my `docker-compose.yml` file that sets up volume mounting (using version 3.7), using [short form syntax](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#short-syntax-3) as specified in the docs:

```
volumes:
    - ./logging:/var/log/cron
```

This maps the relative path `logging` on my host machine to the `/var/log/cron` folder inside the container. When I run `docker-compose up`, if the `logging` folder doesn't exist on my host machine, Docker creates it. All good there.

Now, if I change the above to [long-form syntax](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#long-syntax-3):

```
volumes:
    - type: bind
      source: ./logging
      target: /var/log/cron
```

Now when I run `docker-compose up`, it DOES NOT create `logging` folder if it doesn't exist on my host machine. I get

```
Cannot create container for service app: b'Mount denied:\nThe source path "C:/Users/riptusk331/logging"\ndoesn\'t exist and is not known to Docker'
```

**Does anyone know why the short form syntax creates the host path if it doesn't exist, but the long form does not and gives an error?**

Using Docker Desktop for Windows.